# Transferable zero-knowledge proofs

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Many interactive ZK-proofs satisfy non-transferability; that is, the prover performs a series of actions to convince the verifier of a certain fact, and this verifier can't use this proof to convince another party that this proof is constructed by him.

My questions are:

1. In what case can the ZK proof be transferable and
2. How can such a proof be made?

Comment: Does a Fiat-Shamir transform help you? It makes an interactive proof non-interactive, and has as a side effect that it can be verified non-interactively (by any party).

Comment: @RubenDeSmet A FS NIZK can be also non-transferable.
An example: Let us assume a public key infrastructure. 
Alice can prove to Bob that either $x \in L$ or I know the secret key of Bob. 
Now, this proof convinces Bob of $x\in L$ (we assuming that an honest Bob won't have his key compromised) but Bob cannot transfer this proof to Charlie.

Comment: More details on my last comment in https://eprint.iacr.org/2006/432.pdf